# Capturing Log4j output when executing TestNG tests

Tags: java, log4j, testng

I am executing TestNG tests , and the logging output is set to `DEBUG`, so in case of a failure I can get to inspect exactly what goes wrong.

The problem is that the output is extremely verbose, and it's bothering everyone when it runs . I would like to capture all Log4J logging events - which is easy - and only print them when the test fails. Also, I need to take into account `@Before/@After` methods and also print output for them.

Assuming that I already have a List of Log4J `LoggingEvent`s , how can I print those only when the `Test`/`After`/`Before` methods fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement and register a [org.testng.ITestListener](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/ITestListener.html) and react on the callback methods.

Comment: link is borked, robert

Answer (score 4):

Use Reporter.log(str) to log the message on the report.

```
@AfterMethod
public void printLOGonFailure(ITestResult result) {
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        String  str = getLog();
        Reporter.log(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This site has a explanation on how to do it.](http://slackhacker.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/testing-logging-behaviour-in-four-code-lines-flat/).  I copied the code part here in case the link goes dead.

```
Logger.getLogger(this.getClass())
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,TESTAPPENDER
log4j.appender.TESTAPPENDER=com.my.fantastic.MockedAppender
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

public class FooTest {
    private Appender appenderMock;
    @Before
    public void setupAppender() {
        appenderMock = mock(Appender.class);
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appenderMock);
    }
    @After
    public void removeAppender() {
        Logger.getRootLogger().removeAppender(appenderMock);
    }
    @Test
    public void testMethod()  {
        doStuffThatCausesLogging();
        verify(appenderMock).doAppend((LoggingEvent) anyObject());
    }
}

ArgumentCaptor arguments = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(LoggingEvent.class);
verify(appenderMock).doAppend(arguments.capture());
```

assertThat(arguments.getValue().getLevel(), is(Level.WARN));

Comment: Thanks, it's somehow related, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @user43685: You are right, I added some source code to make it a less rubbish answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put JMockit in dependencies. With it logging testing is very easy.

Put in test class:

```
     @Cascading
final static Logger logging = Logger.getLogger(<some your>.class);
```

Put in test:

```
    testedFunction(a, b, c);
    new Verifications() {{
        logging.error("The message that should be output");
        logging.info("Another message");
    }};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like the below code:

```
@AfterMethod
public void printLOGonFailure(ITestResult result) {
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Create_Case_from_an_Account.class);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("C:\\Users\\svcSelenium\\eclipse-workspace\\SeleniumWork\\classes\\log4j.properties");       
        logger.error("Opps!!Test Failed due to:"+result.getThrowable());
    }
}
```